# HTML form inputs not accepting text with IE11

Tags: html, forms, input, internet-explorer-11

I have a PHP signup page. The form uses standard html for inputs (I believe). It works fine with Safari, Chrome, Firefox, and Edge, but will not accept any input in the input fields with IE11.

You can try the page at (removed - not relevant to solution).

Here is the code I'm using for the form (update - code is fine, not relevant to solution):

```
                         <form method="post" autocomplete="off">

                            <!-- Signup heading  -->
                            <div class="input-logo-image-container">
                                <img class="input-logo-image" style="height:28px;"
                                    src="../common/images/logos/addologo150.png"
                                    alt="Addo•Zone" />
                                <span class="input-logo-text" style="font-size:24px;">Choose a Username</span>
                            </div>  <!-- /infobar-logo-image-container -->

                            <p style="margin: 10px 10px;color: #ccc;">
                                Already have a Username? <a style="color: #99ccff;" href='login.php'>&nbsp;Login</a>
                            </p>
                            <hr>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="email" name="email" id="email"
                                    class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Email Address&#42;"
                                    value="<?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['email']; } ?>"
                                    tabindex="1">
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" name="username" id="username"
                                    class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Username&#42;"
                                    tabindex="2"
                                    value="<?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['username']; } ?>">
                            </div>

                            <!-- Not currently used for input, so hidden -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="hidden" name="usertype" id="usertype" tabindex="5"
                                    value="2">
                            </div>

                            <!-- Not currently used for input, so hidden -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="hidden" name="fullname" id="fullname"
                                    class="form-control input-lg"
                                    value="<?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['fullname']; } ?>"
                                    tabindex="6">
                            </div>

                            <!-- Not currently used for input, so hidden -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="hidden" name="city" id="city"
                                    class="form-control input-lg"
                                    value="<?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['city']; } ?>"
                                    tabindex="7">
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password"
                                            class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Password&#42;"
                                            tabindex="3">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="password" name="passwordConfirm"
                                            id="passwordConfirm" class="form-control input-lg"
                                            placeholder="Confirm Password&#42;" tabindex="4">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
                                <div class="col-xs-4">
                                    <input style="background-color: #336699" type="submit"
                                        name="submit" value="Submit"
                                        class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg" tabindex="5">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
                            </div>

                        </form>
```

Hope you can help me figure this out. I know this must be a common problem, and I'm surprised I can't find other references to it.

Cheers.

Comment: Please look at the source of that page (right click/show source). You have multiple `<!doctype>`,
 `<html>` and `<body>` tags. You should start by cleaning up the html before proceeding.

Comment: Your html is invalid

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I'm not seeing the multiple tags you refer to.  Where are you seeing that?

Comment: Saying the html is invalid isn't helpful, and if it's invalid, why is it only an issue with IE11?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson That's not what the source looks like.  Thx for pointing that out.  I can follow up on that.

Comment: Right click on the actual page and choose "View source" and you will see. It looks like you're including a complete HTML page inside another HTML-page: http://prntscr.com/exrqf8

Comment: Your markup is [invalid](https://validator.nu/?doc=https%3A%2F%2Faddo.zone%2Finputs%2Fsignup.php) and IE a little sissy when it has to deal with such HTML, that's your issue

Comment: The double tags issue has been resolved (obsolete php includes). The html has been cleaned up and validates. IE11 still not accepting any input to form fields. Any other ideas?   Note that in the posted code, some of the input text is all black, and in other cases this site parses it into color based on parameters, etc.  Might a syntax error be staring me in the face?  Thx for your help.

Comment: Also just realized that the entire page is unresponsive.  The hyperlink to login and the submit button don't function either.  Must be something fundamental.

Comment: Also it's unlikely this is a PHP issue, you should be showing us only the HTML code resulting.

Comment: Linking to external code is discouraged; once the code changes this question becomes useless to future visitors.

Comment: You are not going to be serving the page, in its current state, in perpetuity. Therefore there will be no context for the question in the future. This is why you should provide a [mcve] with questions – by not doing so you have a much reduced chance of getting assistance, especially from high-rep users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.  The problem was caused by one of the css style files, which set the z-index of body to -1.  It didn't matter (for IE11 only) that other page elements (main, section, form, div, etc.) had larger and positive z-index numbers.

Changing the z-index for body to +1 solved the problem.